# Jumping dots animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So let's say I have three dots as spans inside a parent element.

I need to create a parent hover animation that will make the dots jump one by one with delay. I accomplished this without hover but I need the animation to work when I hover the parent element. At the moment when I hover the parent element no delay is applied to the children.

```css
.dots-cont {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.dot {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #22303e;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0px 2.5px;
  position: relative;
}

.dots-cont:hover > .dot {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  animation: jump 1s infinite;
}

.dots-cont .dot-1{
  -webkit-animation-delay: 100ms;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
}

.dots-cont .dot-2{
  -webkit-animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
}

.dots-cont .dot-3{
  -webkit-animation-delay: 300ms;
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}

@keyframes jump {
0%   {bottom: 0px;}
20%  {bottom: 5px;}
40%  {bottom: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<span class="dots-cont">
  <span class="dot dot-1"></span>
  <span class="dot dot-2"></span>
  <span class="dot dot-3"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add the `animation` property to `.dot` base instead of the `:hover` version. This way, you will get the same behavior no matter what. You can add any properties you want to the hover class, like changing the color.

```
.dots {
  animation: jump 1s infinite;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3gampq0b/5/

**EDIT: To prevent animation on dot hover.**

```
.dots-cont:hover > .dot {
  animation: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3gampq0b/6/

**EDIT: Only animate on parent hover.**

You can also add padding to the `.dots-cont` so the hover surface area is greater.

```
.dots-cont:hover > * {
  animation: jump 1s infinite;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3gampq0b/7/

Comment: Now they're just jumping without hovering. I don't want to activate animation by hovering individually.

Comment: In that case you can add `animation: none;` in the `:hover` class, so that when you hover it does not jump. Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: No, i want the child elements to jump with delay when i hover the parent element. I couldn't figure out css only solution so i used jquery

Comment: Please see [this update](https://jsfiddle.net/3gampq0b/7/) - you really do not need jQuery for something so simple.

Comment: You're right, the last solution worked perfectly. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

By Using "animation: jump 1s infinite;" directly, you are overriding the animation-delay property for .dot elements.

Try Below snippet, see if this is what you are trying to do:

```css
.dots-cont{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

.dot{
   width: 12px;
   height: 12px;
   background: #22303e;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 50%;
   right: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   margin: 0px 2.5px;
   position: relative;
 }

 .dots-cont:hover > .dot {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    animation-name: jump;
    animation-duration: .3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
   animation-timing-function: ease;
  }

 .dots-cont .dot-1{
 -webkit-animation-delay: 100ms;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
 }

 .dots-cont .dot-2{
   -webkit-animation-delay: 200ms;
    animation-delay: 200ms;
 }

 .dots-cont .dot-3{
   -webkit-animation-delay: 300ms;
   animation-delay: 300ms;
 }
 @keyframes jump {
   from {bottom: 0px}
   to {bottom: 20px}
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes jump {
   from {bottom: 0px}
   to {bottom: 10px}
 }
```

```html
<span class="dots-cont">
  <span class="dot dot-1"></span>
  <span class="dot dot-2"></span>
  <span class="dot dot-3"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
.dots-cont:hover > .dot {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0px;
  animation: jump 1s infinite;
}
```

to

```
.anim .dot {...}
```

Then i add and remove anim class with jQuery.

Comment: Why add jQuery when this was not tagged with Javascript or jQuery? This can be accomplished with just HTML and CSS.

Comment: Added jquery there but i'll try your answer in a second. Thx btw!